# Render partial webform (ASPX) in razor page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-mvc-5

Using MVC 5 in VS2013 (razor engine) - how can I render a partial webform (ASPX page) such that the webform code behind method "Page_Load" will be called, and thus can be debugged?

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/test/menu.aspx")
```

And in the Webform at the top use somthing like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="menu.aspx.cs" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

Just make sure it Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"

Comment: this solution renders the HTML in the partial view (webform) but the webform code behind appears dead - the method Page_Load never appears to be called...

Comment: Are you referencing the webforms library?

Comment: I am not familiar with webforms library.  Which specific library are you referring to please?

Comment: When you first created the project did you select MVC, with webforms

Comment: http://sebnilsson.com/5213308a/render-ascx-files-in-asp-net-mvc-using-only-razorviewengine/

Comment: Created a Proof-of-concept MVC project with webforms and still cannot get a breakpoint in the Page_Load method.  I suspect MVC can render the static parts but cannot preform code-behind functions...

Comment: Check out this link. https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/mixing-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet-mvc